# Requisição ajax em tempo real

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Bem pessoal tenho um script a fazer requisição ajax a cada 1 segundo para me mostrar novo conteúdo mas agora estou a ter um problema que ele a cada 1 segundo actualiza-me o conteúdo todo eu queria que só mostra-se caso exista novo conteúdo na base de dados.

O script que estou a utilizar e este

```
<script>
//LISTA POSTS ESTABELECIMENTOS
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#mostra_posts').load('ajax/mostra_posts.php?id_estabelecimento=<?php echo $row->id; ?>');
    }, 1000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer usado esse script.

Comment: Se você quer o caminho mais correto/recomendado/rapido
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: Você tem como saber no servidor que o conteúdo mudou?

Answer (score 2):

Vocês está usando uma técnica chamada pooling que é ficar perguntando para o servidor de tempo em tempo se tem um novo conteúdo, isso por si só já é pesado e se cada vez que tua requisição bate no servidor o mesmo faça uma leitura em banco se tornará mais pesado ainda, isso pode deixar teu servidor um tanto sobrecarregado. Caso isso aconteça considere o uso de websockets. Segue dois links que possam estar ajudando no assunto [socket cliente](http://socket.io/) e [socket servidor](http://socketo.me/)

Comment: eu nunc trabalhei com websockets queria implementar até porque vou ter um sistema se seguidores com notificações mas pelo que vi isso e complicado

Comment: Você considerou utilizar outro tecnologia que não seja PHP? Com NodeJS isso fica muito simples.

Comment: não mas ao utilizar nodejs deixaria de usar PHP ?

Comment: o problema e que nunca usei isso e nem sei por onde começar nem como instalar isso percebe ?

Comment: Tem como usar as duas tecnologias na mesma aplicação, você teria que trabalhar com dois servidores, e fazer a comunicação entre os servidores. É uma boa solução só que mais complicado.

Comment: mas eu agora já tenho o projecto quase terminado assim teria que fazer todo de novo para usar nodejs que me sugere então para não alterar isso

Comment: Nesse caso você pode continuar utilizando pooling ou tentar implementar o servidor socket em php

Comment: está a falar do Ratchet

Comment: Sim, são muitas variáveis que você tem que considerar para tomar essa decisão, você pode por ex achar que do jeito que está o servidor vai suportar tranquilamente e que implementar ws seria perder tempo. Só você vai poder decidir o que é mais adequado. Eu só estou mostrando que tem outros meios e suas vantagens.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21326/discussion-between-cesar-sousa-and-fabio-lemos-elizandro).

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria cria um outro serviço ajax que notifica caso haja uma alteração ou não, caso seja detectado a alteração só assim então fazer a requisição para atualizar o novo conteúdo.

um exemplo seria:

```
var auto_atualiza = setInterval(function () {
  $.get('possui_alteracao.php', function(data) {
    if (data.possui) {
      $('#meudiv').load('listadados.php');
    }
  });
}, 30000);
```

caso não queira fazer nessa abordagem uma outra seria verificar se houver alteração no DOM, dessa forma:

```
var cachedDOM = $('#meudiv').html();
var auto_atualiza = setInterval(function () {
  $.get('listadados.php', function(data) {
    if(data != cachedDOM) {
      $('#meudiv').html(data);
      cachedDOM = $('#meudiv').html();
    }
  });
}, 30000);
```

Caso necessite de recursos mais avançados de monitoramento de DOM segue uma referência https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: fiz com esse teste mas ele actualiza sempre a div toda o conteúdo todo e nao o conteúdo novo que tem na base de dados náo actualizado os restantes dados